# How find this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}(e^x(1-x))^ndx\right)$

Tags: analysis

**Question:**

Find this limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}(e^x(1-x))^ndx\right)$$

my idea: since $$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
so
$$(1-x)e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1-x)x^k}{k!}$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k(1-x)}{k!}dx\right)$$
then I fell very ugly

Comment: Where is the $n$ exponent gone ?

Comment: Why do I have the nagging impression that all this "my idea" stuff is mainly here to *decorate* the post and to *pretend* that this is not the n-th PSQ by this user? Because I am evil or because it is so?

Answer (score 5):

It is better to exploit
$$\log(1-x) = -x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$ in order to have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}((1-x)e^x)^n\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{n x^2}{2}+n\,O(x^3)\right)\,dx\\ &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{O(x^3)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence the dominated convergence theorem easily gives:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}((1-x)e^x)^n\,dx\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}.$$

Comment: Not so sure ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Of course, this is the correct result but, to get a proof in the classical meaning of the term, one should *control* the approximation in the $O(\ )$ part.

Comment: @Did: To achieve a good control, it is sufficient to prove that over $(0,1)$ we have $$(1-x^3)\leq (1-x)e^{x+x^2/2}\leq(1-x^3/3)$$

Comment: Maybe this is sufficient, if it is, you could show that this holds and how it implies the result. (For the upper bound, try the simpler $1$...)